# Migrate from MySQL to MongoDB - Magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: mysql, mongodb, magento-1.9, migrate

i am using Magento 1.9.3.6 and wanted to know if is it worth it to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB to avoid bottleneck and low latency related to Magento reindexing ?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't replace MySQL with Mongodb completely. MySQL is very powerful with joins and with transactional integrity.
You could however have a combined solution

Comment: I think you should understand what do you need from your database and decide according to that.

Comment: We are managing more than 300k products and more than 100k users per day and we are facing some bottlenecks with Magento indexing/reindexing and locked transactions. I wanted to know if changing the database will be more efficient !?